# Добавления в таблицу class через javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как добавить элементу `<table>` класс, через `Javascript`?

```html
<table id="table">Table</table>
```

Comment: [www.letmegooglethat.com](http://www.letmegooglethat.com/?q=js+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+class+%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8+id)

Comment: document.getElementById("el").classList.add("yourclass");

Comment: а если в td и на tr хочешь задавать класс?

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].classList.add("yourclass");

Раз уж у вас не id, то вместо table используйте и tr и td. 
Но это только для первого найденного элемента, для всех используйте цикл.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let table = document.getElementById("table"); //Находим таблицу

table.classList.add("table"); //Добавляем класс "table"

console.log("Есть ли класс \"table\" у таблицы?: " + table.classList.contains("table") + "!"); //Проверяем, есть ли у таблицы класс "table"
```

```html
<table id="table">Table</table>
```

Comment: вы здесь прям в коде html <table id="table">Table</table> добавили id&

Comment: @NurulloAbdulloev, его тоже можно добавить как и `класс`, просто поиск элемента производить не по `id`, а по `тегу`. К примеру метод `Element.getElementsByTagName()` вам может помочь, a если у вас несколько таблиц, то просто добавить `data-* атрибут и по нему производить поиск`. Можно еще придумать пару способов, но это так же зависит от контекста задачи.

Comment: просто такое случае , в визуальном редакторе (битрикс) создается таблицы , поэтому хотел бы уточнить в <table> добавить class или id\

Comment: @NurulloAbdulloev, я же вас сказал как это сделать. Что вам не понятно?